# firebase messaging notification .dex file cannot exceed 64K on android studio

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

After I add Firebase to receive Push Notifications to my app, it gives me this error:

[image: This is the error message]

I tried to put `multiDexEnabled true` on defaultConfig
and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` on dependencies, but the problem still persists.

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.egcd.egypt"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
```

[image: The build.gradle img]

Any help?

Comment: Where exactly did you put "multiDexEnabled true"?I don't see it in screen shot. May be add whole build.gradle file content into the question...

Comment: You might be using libs that use the same code, so the compiler stucks into a loop. Could you add your entire build.gradle file so we can have more info?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing compile `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'`
from your project dependencies.

You should **never** depend on `com.google.android.gms:play-services` because that is a **gigantic library** that groups together every Google library for android in a single archive.

Instead you should use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-[LIBRARY.YOU.NEED]`